# git - branch HEAD -> FETCH_HEAD

Tags: github

I do conflicts commits and this error is display in pull (remote branch):

error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:

*branch HEAD -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
**application/views/inscricoes.php**
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
Updating cb398ee..026b266**

But, in local repository (my computer), everything is ok. application/views/inscricoes.php  dont show changes. Everything is synchronized.

How could it be possible?

I try so much things, like rebase to past, stash, commit, reset hard...

Some help?

Thanks!

OBS.: I use gitclone in Windows.

Comment: You have some local changes that are not in the upstream. At the moment, best would be to do `git stash` then `git pull` and `git stash apply` so that you don't lose any data. After that if there are any conflicts, then you can manually resolve them.

Comment: I try stash... put in local repository, i have no changes... stash say no changes. So weird. =(

Comment: Try checking your git log and the upstream's git log and see if there are differences. Your branch and upstream's branch might have gone in different directions.

Comment: Make sense to me, I will try in work. Thanks!